# What is the state of App in foreground but appears inactive after few minutes?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, state, foreground

I'm developing an iPad app, and I noticed a state where app appears to be sleep in foreground.

The step to reproduce:

1. Set screen on time for 15 minutes.
2. Launch the app and wait for more than 5 minutes
3. When click the screen after 5 minutes, the app appears to be inactive for 2 seconds and not accepting new events.
4. After 2 seconds, the app registers that touch and begin responding

I'm wondering is the app goes from active foreground to inactive foreground after certain amount of inactivity in foreground?

If so, how long will it take for the app to go to that foreground inactive state. Is there any delegate or notifications that listens to that event happening?

Answer (score 0):

Probably app is Inactive state - The app is running in the foreground, but not receiving events. An iOS app can be placed into an inactive state, for example, when a call or SMS message is received.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that description as well. But I'm confused, as I tested using willResignActiveNoticification is NOT called in this case. There is no message or call because I turned on do not disturb mode when testing.

Comment: what system are you trying? As far as I know there's difference between iOS 13 and earlier versions. Have you read [this?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle)

Comment: Thank you! Although I'm targeting iOS 13, but I'm not currently using the scene approach yet. I read through this article before and I'm reading it again now. Thanks for the link. But it still confuses me a bit, the document says "When launching to the foreground, the system transitions the app to the active state automatically. After that, the state fluctuates between active and background until the app terminates." but I'm not sure if it will actually transition it to inactive state after a certain amount of time in foreground.

Comment: @LegolasWang I have similar thoughts when creating React Native app. It seems that application may transition from Foreground Active to Foreground Inactive state withouth being minimized. Do you have any thoughts after almost 1,5 years :)?